# Can I use JavaScript that is called on page load to modify other elements on the page?

Tags: javascript

I work in advertising. I have a client who has a tracking tag implemented on page load on their advertiser's site. The tracking tag is just a script that calls the JavaScript contained within.

The client is running into a dilemma because they want to trigger another tag when a specific button on the page is clicked on. I don't know the reasoning, but the advertiser's web developers said that it would take them weeks to make the change and the client is aiming to get the tracking set up as soon as possible.

The client's only means of access to the advertiser's page is through the tracking tag called on page load. The client wants to call some JavaScript from the tag that fires on page load that executes a certain function with the button is clicked on. I guess this would involve writing some JavaScript to the document so that it is usable when the button is clicked on.

Questions:

1) Is this possible? In other words, can I take some JavaScript that executes on page load and use it to modify elements on the page?
2) If the button already has another onclick function attached, can we add a second one? The button has a 'class' attribute attached, so could I develop some JavaScript to search for that class attribute and append a second onclick to it? Or would that override the first one?

Note: I cannot use document.write. Would document.appendchild work? Any tips would be appreciated.

To clarify what I want to do again:
1) Trigger JavaScript file on page load. 
2) From within that JavaScript file, send a function to the document/page, and attach the reference to that function to a button with a specific class attribute on the page via an onclick attribute.
3) I do not want to override any existing onclick function on the button.

Thanks,

---

Update:

Here's what I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction (){
    //do something
}
document.getElementsByClassName('test').onclick = myFunction();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button class="test"> Submit Request </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make it so that when the script in the header loads, myFunction is called from the button with class "test". Am I on the right track?

---

Update 2: Would using setAttribute work?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

function myFunction (){
    //do something

}
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()");

</script>

<button class="test"> Submit Request </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes 3.yes -- did you try something yet?

Comment: I will try something and post later. Just was looking for confirmation to see if this was possible.

Comment: @Kamui if you get stuck in trying to accomplish this you can then ask questions on your 1, 2 and 3 separately, which will yield answers to each which you can then put together, or come back to this question and **edit** it with your progress

Comment: I edited my question with my code so far. Please help if you are able to, thanks! :)

Comment: You should use `addEventListener`, not `setAttribute`.

Comment: Any particular reason? When I try both methods I get an error that says cannot ready property 'addEventListener' / 'setAttribute' of undefined.

Comment: I found the solution to my answer elsewhere, thanks for helping! I had to add a function to call my script after the window/document loaded.